# What is the JDBC URL for Oracle's Data Guard Fast-Start Failover?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

Currently I have...

```
url=
"
  jdbc:oracle:thin:@
    (
    DESCRIPTION=
      (
      ADDRESS_LIST=
        (LOAD_BALANCE=OFF)
        (FAILOVER=ON)
        (
        ADDRESS=
          (PROTOCOL=TCP)
          (HOST=10.0.0.6)
          (PORT=1521)
        )
        (
        ADDRESS=
          (PROTOCOL=TCP)
          (HOST=10.0.0.7)
          (PORT=1521)
        )
      )
      (
      CONNECT_DATA=
        (SERVICE_NAME=mySID.nowhere.org)
        (SERVER=DEDICATED)
      )
     )
"
```

Comment: And... what? What's the problem you are experiencing? More details, please.

Comment: Did you already check "Data Sources and URLs" from Oracle (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't setup Fast-Start Failover in the URL.  It's something that you setup on the data source using the setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true) function call.

Per [here](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/java/jdbc/High_Availability/FastConnectionFailoverExampleThin.java)

> An application enables Fast Connection Failover by calling
>   setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true) on a DataSource instance, before
>   retrieving any connections from that instance.
>
> You cannot enable Fast Connection Failover when reinitializing a connection
>   cache. You must enable it before using the OracleDataSource instance.

For example

```
    ods = new OracleDataSource();
    ...
    ods.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
```

Also, it mentions:

> FAST CONNECTION FAILOVER PREREQUISITES
>
> 1.) The implicit connection cache is enabled. Fast Connection Failover
>   works in conjunction with the JDBC connection caching mechanism.
>   This helps applications manage connections to ensure high
>   availability.
>
> 2.) The application uses service names to connect to the database; the
>   application cannot use service IDs (ORACLE_SID). Use a service name
>   rather than an SID when setting the OracleDataSource url property.
>
> 3.) The underlying database has Release 10 (10.1) or Release 10 (10.2)
>   Real Application Clusters (RAC) capability. If failover events are
>   not propagated, connection failover cannot occur.
>
> 4.) Oracle Notification Service (ONS) is configured and available on the
>   node where JDBC is running and on the Oracle RAC. JDBC depends on
>   ONS to propagate database events from RAC and notify JDBC of them.
>   If ONS is not correctly set up, then implicit connection cache
>   creation fails and an ONSException is thrown at the first
>   getConnection request.
>
> 5.) The JVM in which your JDBC instance is running must have
>   oracle.ons.oraclehome set to point to your ORACLE_HOME. For example:
>
> -Doracle.ons.oraclehome=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1
>
> 6.) Set the FastConnectionFailoverEnabled property before making the
>   first getConnection request to an OracleDataSource. When Fast
>   Connection Failover is enabled, the failover applies to all 
>   connections in the connection cache. If your application explicitly
>   creates a connection cache using the Connection Cache Manager, then
>   you must first set FastConnectionFailoverEnabled before retrieving
>      any connections.
>
> 7.) The ons.jar must be part of the CLASSPATH for the application.
>   The ons.jar can be found in the Oracle Client installation.

---

**Edit:**
One last thought, if there ever is a failover, you will need to handle the SQLException:

> ORA-17008: Closed Connection